# RegEx Match strings that include a substring while excluding other words that also have that substring

Tags: regex

I am trying to match certain log entries that include the partial string **"Number"** while *excluding other log entries that also include the string* **"Number"**.

someNumber=12345
anotherNumber=45678
thirdNumber=010101
otherNumber=99999
<someNumber>12345
<anotherNumber>45678
<thirdNumber>010101
<otherNumber>99999

I need to match all entries that include the string **"Number"** while excluding only some of them.
So, *all occurrences of* ***"thirdNumber"*** *and* ***"otherNumber"*** *(whether followed b = or >)* need to match.  While **"someNumber"** and **"anotherNumber"** need to be excluded from the match.

Note, that some of the log entries include an equal sign (someNumber=12345) and others are surrounded by XML tags (<someNumber>12345)

Additionally, on occasion you have partial matches that need to be excluded (i.e. the substring "other" is inside the log entry "an**other**Number=".

What I am trying:
(?!.*(\bsomeNumber|\banotherNumber))(Number.)

Doesn't seem to work for me.  Any help appreciated.

Comment: Do you strictly need to do this in **one** regex?? Your solution might look simpler if you first filter for "lines that contain `Number`", and *then* filter for "lines that don't contain  `someNumber` or `anotherNumber`".

Answer (score 0):

One option might be

```
<?\b(?!someNumber|anotherNumber)\b\w+Number[=>]\d+
```

The pattern matches:

- `<?` Match optional `<`
- `\b(?!someNumber|anotherNumber)\b` A word boundary, assert not any or the 2 words directly to the right using a negative lookahead
- `\w+Number` Match 1+ word characters followed by `Number`
- `[=>]\d+` Match either `=` or `>` and 1+ digits

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ruzUHv/1)

---

If a [conditional](https://www.regular-expressions.info/conditional.html) is supported, you could make the pattern a bit stricter matching a closing `>` when there is an opening `<`, else match an `=`

```
(<)?\b(?!someNumber|anotherNumber)\b\w+Number(?(1)>|=)\d+
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/aJSwX7/1)

Comment: Thanks to everyone for their answers.  I ended up using @The fourth bird answer with some slight changes for additional criteria needed.  Really appreciate the help. This was hurting my brain for a while prior to your answers.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that this requirement isn't particularly important:

> Note, that some of the log entries include an equal sign (someNumber=12345) and others are surrounded by XML tags (12345)

How about:

```
\b(?!(?:some|another))\w+Number
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/cCOdza/1)

Answer (score 0):

Use a negative look ahead for the blacklist:

```
\b(?!(someNumber|otherNumber)\b)\w+Number\b
```

See [live demo](https://rubular.com/r/eDsknWfH441cAH).

Note that the negative look ahead needs to include the word boundary for the expression correctly *match* the edge case `someNumberNumber` et al.